# Error:(232) Ignore: Unknown issue id "InlineApi"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, build-error

I'm on windows and updated to Android Studio (AS) 3.0 RC1. When I try to generate apk, it gives below error

> Error:(232) Ignore: Unknown issue id "InlineApi" [LintError]

Project build is successful but unable to generate signed apk

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @AbhishekV after commenting some lines in build.gradle removed the error. But I'm not sure whether that approach was correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be "InlinedApi". See https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint-checks

Answer (score 0):

in **build.gradle** , changing the line from `fatal 'NewApi', 'InlineApi'` to `fatal 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'` solved the issue for me